# Remove tabs from product data in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to remove the below tabs from the product data
1- 'Get more option' Tab
2- 'woocommerce tab'
3- Upsell
4- Cross-sell
As shown in the screenshot  https://prnt.sc/pp1oyy

I wrote the below function but not working

```
function remove_tab($tabs){
unset($tabs['get_more_options']); // it is to remove general tab
unset($tabs['woocommerce_tab']); // it is to remove variations tab
return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_tab', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Get more options" suggestions tab were added in Woocommerce 3.6 and you can disable it by either going to **Woocommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> "Woocommerce.com"** and untick the checkbox "Show suggestions".

Another way is to add the following code to your themes functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_allow_marketplace_suggestions', '__return_false' );
```

In terms of the "Woocommerce tab" - if you want to remove upsells & cross sells you can add the follow code:

```
function remove_tab($tabs){
    unset($tabs['linked_product']); // Removes the tab section for cross & upsells
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_tab', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Hello
About upsells & cross-sells there is 'Custom related product' placed in this tab as u see in the below screenshot, thats why i wanna remove just the upsells & cross-sells not the tab
https://prnt.sc/ppun24